# Pandas: Nesting Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I want to store a dataframe in another dataframe cell. 
I have a data that looks like this [image]

I have daily data which consists of date, steps, and calories. In addition, I have minute by minute HR data of a specific date. Obviously it would be easy to put the minute by minute data in 2 dimensional list but I'm fearing that would be harder to analyze later. 
What would be the best practice when I want to have both data in one dataframe? Is it even possible to even nest dataframes? 
Any better ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: you might want to use [`zarr`](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  or [`xarray`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) instead of `pandas`. it provides N-dimensional arrays and dataframes and it seems to me that is what you need.

Comment: R is able to do this very well, JSYK,  It is a little harder with pandas because you can't store the data frame in a data frame.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, currently pandas is only my option

Comment: @DemetriP, why not? See my answer below

Comment: @sacul Oh!  I tried a naive way of doing this, but I seem to be mistaken.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/2641825) about the opposite operation: unnest. An equivalent to R's unnest function is no now available in pandas and it's called "explode".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, it seems possible to nest dataframes but I would recommend **instead rethinking how you want to structure your data**, which depends on your application or the analyses you want to run on it after.

## How to "nest" dataframes into another dataframe

Your dataframe containing your nested "sub-dataframes" won't be displayed very nicely. However, just to show that it is possible to nest your dataframes, take a look at this mini-example:

Here we have 3 random dataframes:

```
>>> df1
          0         1         2
0  0.614679  0.401098  0.379667
1  0.459064  0.328259  0.592180
2  0.916509  0.717322  0.319057
>>> df2
          0         1         2
0  0.090917  0.457668  0.598548
1  0.748639  0.729935  0.680409
2  0.301244  0.024004  0.361283
>>> df3
          0         1         2
0  0.200375  0.059798  0.665323
1  0.086708  0.320635  0.594862
2  0.299289  0.014134  0.085295
```

We can make a main dataframe that includes these dataframes as values in individual "cells":

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx':[1,2,3], 'dfs':[df1, df2, df3]})
```

We can then access these nested datframes as we would access any value in any other dataframe:

```
>>> df['dfs'].iloc[0]
          0         1         2
0  0.614679  0.401098  0.379667
1  0.459064  0.328259  0.592180
2  0.916509  0.717322  0.319057
```